# Python logging, how to prevent functions from library from logging?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm making a project and using a library from the requirements of the project. The library implements logging and automatically logs to a file, when I call its functions.

Now, I'm implementing logging by myself, and only want my own messages to be logged to the file and not the library messages.

One solution I thought of would be switching the logging file each time I call a function from the library and then removing that file, but that seems overly complicated and clutterly. What can I do in order to not log the messages from the library?

P.S.:

I'm using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library and I initalize it as:

```
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO,filename = loggingFile,format = "%(message)s")
```

, which means, all messages from myself and from the library will get logged in `loggingFile`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if we can exactly help. This might be a risky move, but you could try to replace the `logging` module with your own.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries [should not directly output anything to logs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) - that should be done only by handlers configured by an application. A library that logs output is [an anti-pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-handlers-other-than-nullhandler-to-a-logger-in-a-library) - if a library definitely does that, I'd log a bug against that library's issue tracker.

On the other hand, it might be that the library is only outputting stuff because you have configured output via your `basicConfig()` call. If you need more than basic configuration, don't use`basicConfig()` - use the other APIs provided.

Comment: In either case, you can use the `removeHandler` method for the appropriate `Logger` instance to remove the `FileHandler` that writes to the given file.